# SUM(COUNT(column)*AVG(column)) AS column

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop

I am using hadoop on csv to analyze some data. I use sql/mysql (not sure) to analyze the data, and now I am on an impass.

I spent googling this hours and hours without finding anything even remotely related. I need to have a query where I take count of a column and either sum or average of column and multiply them with each other.

This doesnt work:

```
SELECT model, 
       brand, 
       COUNT(model) AS ModelCount, 
       AVG(distance) AS DistanceAvg, 
       // OR SUM(distance) AS DistanceSum 
       // SUM(ModelCount * DistanceAvg) AS Total
       // SUM(ModelCount * DistanceSum) AS Total 
       // SUM(COUNT(model)*AVG(distance)) AS Total
       // SUM(COUNT(model)*SUM(distance)) AS Total
       // None of the commented lines work
FROM cars 
WHERE type = 'M1' OR type = 'M1G' 
GROUP BY model, brand 
ORDER BY ModelCount DESC;
```

The rest of the code works just fine, but none of the commented solutions work. Hours of googling, no luck.

There seems to be issues understanding what I am after, what I need to figure out is how to get a result from multiplying counted value with averaged value as follows:

```
SUM(COUNT(model)*AVG(distance)) AS TOTAL
```

I want to count the models to find out how many of them exists, that works just fine. Then I want to get the average distance driven with the model out of all cars which I get with the group by functioning. And THEN I want the query to multiply the number of cars with the average distance driven with those particular cars.

I can get the values I need and manually calculate the value, I'd just hoped there was a way to skip manually calculating this, since it is a huge work to do on this scale. There is literally 5 million cars in that list, I cant work manually on these conditions.

Not sure if this helps, but heres working query, where I need this added:

```
SELECT mallimerkinta, 
       merkkiSelvakielinen, 
       COUNT(mallimerkinta) AS Suosituinmalli, 
       ROUND(AVG(CAST(matkamittarilukema AS FLOAT)),0) AS Keskilukema   
FROM ajoneuvot 
WHERE ajoneuvoluokka = 'M1' OR ajoneuvoluokka = 'M1G' 
GROUP BY mallimerkinta, merkkiSelvakielinen 
HAVING COUNT(mallimerkinta) > '4659' 
ORDER BY Keskilukema DESC;
```

Here are the results it generates:

```
mallimerkinta   merkkiselvakielinen     suosituinmalli  keskilukema

4D COROLLA 1.6XLI-AE101L-AEMDKW/247     Toyota  4715    267686.0

5D MONDEO STW 1.8-BWY/275   Ford    6021    226086.0

5D FOCUS STW 1.6-DNW/262    Ford    10571   216980.0

5D GOLF VARIANT 1.6-1J/250  Volkswagen  13136   200201.0

V70 Farmari (AC) 4ov 2400cm3 A  Volvo   5912    198062.0

4D FOCUS HATCHBACK 1.6-DAW/262  Ford    5899    197925.0

4D BORA SEDAN 1.6-1J/250    Volkswagen  4660    180550.0

5D COROLLA STW 1.6-ZZE121L-DWMDKW/260   Toyota  4999    180221.0

5D COROLLA STW 1.6-ZZE121L-DWMNKW/260   Toyota  4990    176687.0

4D ALMERA SEDAN 1.5-BAAN16/254  Nissan  8421    156514.0

XC60 Farmari (AC) 4ov 2400cm3 A     Volvo   7900    113591.0

GOLF Farmari (AC) 4ov 1390cm3   Volkswagen  6215    87724.0

FOCUS Farmari (AC) 4ov 1596cm3  Ford    5063    86598.0

GOLF Farmari (AC) 4ov 1390cm3 A     Volkswagen  5634    83164.0

CEED Monik�ytt�ajoneuvo (AF) 4ov 1591cm3    Kia     5191    78059.0

TOYOTA AVENSIS Monik�ytt�ajoneuvo (AF) 4ov 1798cm3  Toyota  6384    68166.0

NISSAN QASHQAI Monik�ytt�ajoneuvo (AF) 4ov 1598cm3  Nissan  10595   59330.0

FIESTA Viistoper� (AB) 4ov 1242cm3  Ford    5631    58837.0

TOYOTA AURIS Monik�ytt�ajoneuvo (AF) 4ov 1798cm3    Toyota  5558    56878.0

TOYOTA YARIS Monik�ytt�ajoneuvo (AF) 4ov 1329cm3    Toyota  11829   40348.0
```

I need suosituinmalli multiplied by keskilukema as an additional column.

Comment: you can't use aliases previously defined in the same query, which is the reason your commented lines won't work. use the actual calculations instead of aliases and it will work.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean of your script, just give a clear sample data and a clear sample result.

Comment: vkp, the commented section does include the actualy calculations as an option or then I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: just give an example if you want to solve that problem. Table example data.

Comment: I edited the original post in hopes doing what you wanted me to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT mallimerkinta, 
       merkkiSelvakielinen, 
       COUNT(mallimerkinta) AS Suosituinmalli, 
       ROUND(AVG(CAST(matkamittarilukema AS FLOAT)),0) AS Keskilukema,
      COUNT(mallimerkinta) * ROUND(AVG(CAST(matkamittarilukema AS FLOAT)),0) AS DesiredColumn
FROM ajoneuvot 
WHERE ajoneuvoluokka = 'M1' OR ajoneuvoluokka = 'M1G' 
GROUP BY mallimerkinta, merkkiSelvakielinen 
HAVING COUNT(mallimerkinta) > '4659' 
ORDER BY Keskilukema DESC;
```

Can Also be Done like so:

```
SELECT
    t.*
    ,t.Suosituinmalli * t.Keskilukema AS DesiredColumn
FROM
    (
       SELECT mallimerkinta, 
            merkkiSelvakielinen, 
            COUNT(mallimerkinta) AS Suosituinmalli, 
            ROUND(AVG(CAST(matkamittarilukema AS FLOAT)),0) AS Keskilukema,
       FROM ajoneuvot 
       WHERE ajoneuvoluokka = 'M1' OR ajoneuvoluokka = 'M1G' 
       GROUP BY mallimerkinta, merkkiSelvakielinen 
       HAVING COUNT(mallimerkinta) > '4659' 
    ) t
ORDER BY Keskilukema DESC;
```

What the others are saying in their comments are that you cannot use Column Aliases in the definition of another dynamic column.  So In your example above you stated `SUM(ModelCount * DistanceAvg)`  but `ModelCount` and `DistanceAvg` are column aliases for the same select statement so they cannot be reference like that however you could have done `(COUNT(MODEL) * AVG(DISTANCE))`.  So there are 2 ways to fix the issue either repeat the definitions for your columns you want to reference in the definition of your new column such as the first example.  Or the second is you could have turned your select statement into a sub select.  The outer select would then understand your column aliases and allow you to use them in the definition of a new dynamic column.

Comment: Glad the answer helped you out.  Please accept my answer so others no the question has been solved and you do not need further work.  Here is an article about how /when to do so.  Thanks and welcome to stackoverflow http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work